# Passing Multiple Arguments to GraphQL Query

Tags: sparql, graphql

**First thing**

Appreciate this may be a bit of a stupid question, but I'm working with GraphQL having come from the RDF/Linked Data world and having a lot of trouble getting my head around how I would return a set. Essentially I want something where I could select, let's say a list of `Characters` (using the examples from the GraphQL docs) via their `id`. In SPARQL I'd be using the `VALUES` clause and then binding, something like:

```
VALUES { <http://uri/id-1> <http://uri/id-2> <http://uri/id-3> }
```

I'd assume something like this would be what I'd want (pseudocode)

```
{
  human(id: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]) {
    name
    height
  }
}
```

[Aliases](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) kind of do what I want, but I don't want to have to specify in advance or manually what the different named return values are - I want to say in my code pass a list of IDs:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

...and have a query that could accept that array of IDs and return me results in a predictable non-scalar shape as per the pseudo-query above.

**Second thing**

I'm also assuming that it's in fact not possible to have a query resolve to either a `Human` or `[Human]` - that it has to be one or the other? No biggie if so, I'd just settle for the latter... but I think I'm just generally quite confused over this now.

Comment: For example, am I thinking about this wrong, and I should define say a `Slice` type where I can define multiple arguments to chop up a hypothetical list into ranges? Even so, that kind of feels sub optimal for processing lists of resources.

Comment: And ideally I'd like to avoid having a string input like `"[1 2 3 4 5]"` so I don't have to worry about parsing, although I suppose that's a last ditch option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First you need to extend you query by adding a "humans":

```
extend type Query {
  humans(listId: [String!]): [Human!]
  human(id: ObjID!): Human
}
```

Second - write a resolver for it.

```
Query: {
  humans(root, {listId}, { Human }) {
    return Human.fillAllByListId(listId);
  },
  ...
},
```

List of IDs could be passed as follows:
[image: pass list of IDs]

Answer (score 7):

You can use [GraphQL Aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases)

```
{
    first: human(id: "1") {
        name
        height
    }
    second: human(id: "2") {
        name
        height
    }
}
```

Comment: works without adjusting the serverside, perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Whit Hasura you can do like this (IDK if that working only on Hasura)

```
query getConfigurationList($ids: [String!]!) {
    configuration (where: {id:{_in: $ids}}){
        id
        value
    }
}
```

Here is the [docs](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html#list-based-search-operators-in-nin)